# Wifi Icon Missing

Tags: wireless, network-manager, icons

I know there are current threads that have been solved for this issue, but none of them have seemed to help me.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

My wifi icon on the top has disappeared, I can still connect to the internet through Network in System Settings, but I cannot see if I am connected.

I done this:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

Remove file `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state` :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
```

Start network manager back:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

And that hasn't worked. I've tried a few other things but I'm sorry I forget what else there was.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for is installing
    sudo apt-get install network-manager
and
    sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
then restart your computer

Comment: Your steps will install NetworkManager, but the question does not indicate this isn't installed for the OP. Instead, it even shows it is. Not sure how this is useful for this actual question, so -1.